# Are data acquisition system and 'microcomputer on instrumentation design" and data logger the same thing?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, instrumentation, datalogger, data-acquisition

**This is data logger-:**

[image]

**This is data acquisition system-:**

[image]

**This is "micrcomputer on instrumentation design"**

[image]

All 3 look quite similar. What is the difference between each of them? Sadly, there are not many great resources to learn about these topics. So really hard for beginner to understand all of this on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really they are mostly the same thing, the software and features are different.

A data acquisition is only for measurement, storage and processing are elsewere.

A data logger is aimed only at measurement and storage. It gives you a temporal series.

A computer instrumentation system can do mostly whatever it needs to be done.

So it's mostly an evolution of features but maybe a data logger can keep a year worth of data while the instrumentation PC only cares about the last five minutes, it's application dependant. In the same way many DAQ have some memory to keep the data before processing (Fluke called them 'data buckets').

Also there's a legislative/standard/certification thing, for example food fridges must have a *data logger* that keeps *inalterable* data for auditing in some areas.

Comment: Thanks specially DAQ and microcomputer on instrumentation design looks exactly similar to me. Even Data logger isn't that much difference if we don't take it literally. I got confused if I was just hypothetically thinking sth as there are no learning resources available for this topic. It cleared up my confusion.

Comment: @fekmut, if that's the case, upvote this and select it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

DAQ stands for Data Acquisition. For example a DAQ card consists of an input analog circuit or AFE - Analog Front End, and the ADC. The DAQ card doesn't consist of a processing computer, storage, etc it's a bare acquisition board.

DAQ system usually is a complete package of DAQ cards (also multiple of them) a software that processes the incoming data and stores the results.

Data Logger is a device that stores data, possibly it has also an ADC + simple analog conditioner, if analog data is being recorded.

Usually a DAQ system is some high end product used in laboratory, industry, research, ...that is very expensive and very accurate, high dynamic. Meanwhile a data logger usually is a handheld, cheap it has limitations but it could be just enough for non demanding measurements.